# How can someone write H\Z in latex?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can someone write H\Z in LaTeX and/or overelaf? `$H\Z$` it does not work with `$$` as you can see.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In regular text mode, you can use `H\textbackslash Z`; in math mode, use `$H\backslash Z$` or  `$H\setminus Z$` depending on the use case.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what you think H\Z means, then it is a lot easier to guide you to the proper solution. My guess is the same as Jasper, note that `$H\backslash Z$` and `$H\setminus Z$` isn't really the same thing which I ask what it is suppose to mean.